# position of image in a div for mobile

Tags: html, image, resize

I am editing a bootstrap site but the main top picture on mobile devices doesn't resize

any ideas?

here is the demo link for the website:

https://freehtml5.co/demos/nuptial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this

Add these styles for mobile devices only:

```
background-size:100% contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:40% 0
```

Comment: hi Thank for this, it works as in it fits it to the correct width but seems to fill the div by repeating.. is there a way to have the correct height? thanks in advance

Comment: Did u add background-repeat:no-repeat; ?

Comment: I added that yes :)

Comment: it still repeats though?

Comment: Hey it works perfect, I had some incorrect code!! thank you So much!!!!